# Post request content using Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I tried to move the routing from the Express App to another file, it works but when I try to get the body of the post request, it's undefined.

Here is the server.js file :

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
winston.add(winston.transports.Console, {colorize: true});
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'server.err', level: 'error'});
winston.info('Starting server.');

var Firebase = require('firebase-admin');
var connection = require('./connection/firebaseConnection.json');

var express = require('express')
app = express();
var router = require('./srcs/router');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

try {
  Firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: Firebase.credential.cert({
      projectId: connection.firebase.project_id,
      clientEmail: connection.firebase.client_email,
      privateKey: connection.firebase.private_key
    }),
    databaseURL: 'https://' + connection.firebase.project_id + '.firebaseio.com'
  });
  winston.info('Connected to Firebase.');
} catch (error) {
  winston.error('Could not connect to Firebase : ' + error.code + ' : ' + error.message);
  process.exit(1);
}

app.use('/', router);

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var origin = req.headers.origin;
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST', 'GET');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,X-Requested-With');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  return next();
});

var server = app.listen(80, function() {
  winston.info('Server listening on port 80.');
});
```

And here is the router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var winston = require('winston');

router.post('/post', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I did a curl on it using this command :

```
curl --data "title=test" http://localhost/post
```

And the router.post is triggered but the value is undefined.

Comment: Try adding the bodyParser middleware (the `app.use` call) before the router middleware call.

Comment: It worked, thanks !

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the bodyParser middleware (the app.use call) before the router middleware call.

The middlewares are run in the order in which they are added. You want the `bodyParser` to execute before reaching the router.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

app.use('/', router);
```